# What's the meaning of "might as well end right now"

Tags: slang

I can feel what kind of meaning this sentence has, but I guess I need more specific explanation, I would be appreciate it if you could help me

You **might as well end right now** if that’s your poor little goal

Comment: Why does this question have to downvotes? I don't get it....if someone is learning English, he or she might not be able to tell that it is agrammatical.

Comment: @Lambie - When I hover over the downvote button, I see an tooltip that reads, "This question does not show any research." I think it's a fair question, but, unfortunately, in its current state, it's worthy of a couple downvotes, too. The OP ought to at least provide more [Details, please](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/439/please-everyone-details-please).

Comment: Sorry, but we often have questions without any "research" and it doesn't seem to bother people.

Comment: @Lambie - I agree that voting is not always consistent, but I wouldn't hold up other poorly-research questions as good examples.

Answer (score 3):

Well, that's not very nice. But in any case,  the sentence is missing a pronoun.  End what?  Usually we would at the very least say something like:

> You might as well end **it** right now.

meaning either "give up" or, more extreme, "kill yourself".

As I said, not very nice.

Edit:  The sentence as written is the *transitive* use of the verb "to end", which implies *someone* (or something) **ends** something else:

> I am ending this interview right now!
>
> Let us end this meeting on a positive note.

With the transitive use, a direct object is required, even if just the vague pronoun "it".  Also (as cbh notes in the comment below), a nasty suggestion like "You should end it all!" is still transitive, where "it" means "your life".

[More on transitive and intransitive verbs](http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/transitive-and-intransitive-verbs)

Comment: Thanks Andrew, based on my searches there's no need for a pronoun for such a sentence, like:
"The world may as well end right now"
"My life might as well end right now"

... actually I think "kill yourself" make more sense to me in this phrase

Comment: @Nima there are different ways the verb "to end" can be used.  There's the intransitive, where something *ends* and the transitive, where someone *ends* something.  If there is a subject (e.g. "you") and the sentence implies *something else* ends, then it's the transitive use, and a direct object is required. [More on transitive/intransitive verbs](http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/transitive-and-intransitive-verbs)

Comment: @Nima Although *end* can sometimes be intransitive, that usage doesn't make sense if the subject is a person.  When used with the meaning of "kill yourself," the usual phrase is "end it" (with "it" implied to mean "your life").

Comment: @Andrew I forgot to mention that I just did copy/paste this sentence, so I didn't write it on my own, it's actually by A.J.Hoge in one of his lessons

Comment: @Nima thank goodness, although it's not unusual to see mean little comments like that on internet forums.

Comment: @Andrew although I'm not agree with you on your last comment ;) , but I want to appreciate your quick response and your detailed explanations

Comment: With no context provided, it's hard to say if this is "not very nice." Imagine a child throwing a tantrum; a parent might say: "You might as well end right now; we're not buying the toy." There's nothing un-nice about that. In fact, I'd regard it as an appropriate response.

Comment: @J.R. if it was just "you may as well end (it) right now." I could see your take on it.  But the "poor little goal" is so condescending that it seems obvious there is bad intent.  Plus, at first, I assumed this was a comment directed at Nima -- who I assume is not a child.

Comment: @Andrew - I just wanted to point out that "You might as well end it right now" by itself is not necessarily "not nice" – something that a learner might have a hard time picking up on by reading your answer. But at least now we've clarified things down here some.